Are closures of components of $U\cap V$ disjoint, if $U$ and $V$ are open connected sets?
Let $U$ and $V$ be connected open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (or more generally connected and locally connected space). Is it true that connected components of $U\cap V$ have pairwise disjoint closures in $\mathbb R^n$?
I have tried some common strategies and I am really stuck. I know that such components are disjoint and open in $\mathbb R^n$, hence $\operatorname{cl} S\cap T=\emptyset=S\cap\operatorname{cl}T$ for distinct $S$ and $T$ being such components. Also, the assertion is not true for arbitrary open sets (consider two open squares on the plane with a vertex in common).
EDIT. Actually I realised that there is a counterexample, because these two open squares can be represented as the intersection of two connected open sets. Originally there was one more assumption that $U$ and $V$ have connected complements.
EDIT. As noted in the comments, for $n\geq 3$ we can easily construct counterexamples. That's why the question remains open only for the case $n=2$.

Does this work?
For $n \ge 2$, take some point $x \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, let $U := B_{\lVert x\rVert}(x) \cup B_{\lVert x\rVert}(-x) \cup C$, where the $B$s are open balls and $C$ is an open connection such that $0 \notin C$.
Define $V$ similarly as $V := B_{\lVert x\rVert}(x) \cup B_{\lVert x\rVert}(-x) \cup \tilde{C}$, where $\tilde{C}$ is an open connection such that $0 \notin \tilde{C}$ and  $C \cap \tilde{C} = \varnothing$.
Then our connected components of $U \cap V$ are precisely $B_{\lVert x\rVert}(x)$ and $B_{\lVert x\rVert}(-x)$, and their closures intersect at $0$.

Is the term "open connection" (or simple "connection") a conventional term in general topology? Or is it just used in this comment (to emphasize that the union of $C$ or $\widetilde{C}$ with both balls form a connected subspace)? Just out of curiosity.

@Lemmon, yes I think this works. Let me edit the question to ask specifically about $n=2$.

@Kulisty Lemmon’s comment works for $n = 2$ as well. Just in case, I’ll write a more explicit example when $n = 2$.

@Ikeroy I think the more conventional way of expressing this would be "$C$ is such that the resulting set is open and connected", I haven't seen any use of the term before outside informal discussions. I was butting up against the character limit mainly.

Let $U = (0, 2) \times (0, 1)$ and $V = [(0, 1) \times (0, 2)] \cup [(0, 2) \times (1, 2)] \cup [(1, 2) \times (0, 2)]$. Then $U$ and $V$ are both open connected, and $U \cap V = [(0, 1) \times (0, 1)] \cup [(1, 2) \times (0, 1)]$ has two connected components whose closures intersect.
